# How to pass values arguments to modal.show() function in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-events

I have a page the shows a list of local cafes. When the user clicks on a certain cafe, a modal dialog is shown, that already has the "cafe name" pre-filled. The page contains many cafe names, and the form should contain the "cafe name" that he clicked on.

Following is the list of cafe names generated as text with link button

```
         <table class="table table-condensed  table-striped">
      <tbody>   
        <tr>
          <td>B&Js
          </td>
          <td>10690 N De Anza Blvd </td>
          <td>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onClick="$('#createFormId').modal('show')" >Announce</a>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>CoHo Cafe
          </td>
          <td>459 Lagunita Dr </td>
          <td>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onClick="$('#createFormId').modal('show')" >Announce</a>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>Hot Spot Espresso and Cafe
          </td>
          <td>1631 N Capitol Ave </td>
          <td>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onClick="$('#createFormId').modal('show')" >Announce</a>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the modal form

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="createFormId"">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h3>Create Announcement</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" commandName="announceBean" action="/announce" >
        <input type="hidden" name="cafeId" value="104" />
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="cafeName">Where I am Coding</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="cafeName" name="cafeName" class="input-xlarge disabled" type="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="B&amp;Js"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="date" name="date" />
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="create" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Cancel" onclick="closeDialog ();" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Question is how to pass actual value into the "value" attribute of the modal form?

```
<input type="hidden" name="cafeId" value="104" />
```

The form "show" event is triggered by "onlick" event

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onClick="$('#createFormId').modal('show')" >Announce</a>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary announce" data-toggle="modal" data-id="107" >Announce</a>
```

Then use jQuery to bind the click and send the Announce data-id as the value in the modals #cafeId:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".announce").click(function(){ // Click to only happen on announce links
     $("#cafeId").val($(this).data('id'));
     $('#createFormId').modal('show');
   });
});
```

Comment: Works great, but how can I get the fade in effect? Doesn't same to work with the commands.

Comment: @Mittchel most likely its too late but you can get fade effect if you remove the `hide` class from the div

Comment: I can not find where is the `".announce"` in his original code?

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#createFormId').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        $("#cafeId").val($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: @briansol: yes, typically you would use 'show' to set a value, since you don't need to wait for CSS transitions to complete: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage). Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i am calling my modal

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="190" data-target="#modal-popup">Open</a>
```

Here's how i am obtaining value in the modal

```
$('#modal-popup').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    console.log($(e.relatedTarget).data('id')); // 190 will be printed
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to share how I did this. I spent the last few days rattling my head with how to pass a couple of parameters to the bootstrap modal dialog. After much head bashing, I came up with a rather simple way of doing this.

Here is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editGroupNameModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="editGroupName" class="modal-header">Enter new name for group </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= form_tag( { action: 'update_group', port: portnum } ) do %>
          <%= text_field_tag( :gid, "", { type: "hidden" })  %>
          <div class="input-group input-group-md">
          <span class="input-group-addon" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 3;" >Name</span>
          <%= text_field_tag( :gname, "", { placeholder: "New name goes here", class: "form-control", aria: {describedby: "basic-addon1"}})  %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the simple javascript to change the gid, and gname input values:

```
function editGroupName(id, name) {
    $('input#gid').val(id);
    $('input#gname.form-control').val(name);
  }
```

I just used the onclick event in a link:

```
//                                                                              &#39; is single quote
//                                                                                   ('1', 'admin')
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editGroupNameModal" onclick="editGroupName(&#39;1&#39;, &#39;admin&#39;); return false;" href="#">edit</a>
```

The onclick fires first, changing the value property of the input boxes, so when the dialog pops up, values are in place for the form to submit.

I hope this helps someone someday.  Cheers.

Comment: This is ruby syntax.