# Inserting values in a modal form only when it's opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got a simple form that opens in a modal window to let visitors save a photo to a 'lightbox' to refer back to later. It loads from a page that only shows the one photo, so that photo ID is written into the form as the page loads.

I'd like to offer the same function from a page showing multiple photos though, but can't work out how to get (just) the required photoid into the form/modal?

Previously I've done this easily enough with popup windows, passing the id in the querystring, but I'd like to get away from that... if there's a way to modify the text of the modal as it's opened?

Any ideas much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found an existing solution eventually... link below if anyone else is looking... [How to pass values to a modal show function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379624/how-to-pass-values-arguments-to-modal-show-function-in-bootstrap)